# For each $n$ is it possible to have $\mathrm{crit}(x^{[n]}*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x^{[n-1]}*y)>\dots>\mathrm{crit}(x*y)$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, self-distributivity

Suppose that $(X,*,1)$ satisfies the following identities:
$x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z),1*x=x,x*1=1$. Define the Fibonacci terms $t_{n}(x,y)$ for $n\geq 1$ by letting 
$$t_{1}(x,y)=y,t_{2}(x,y)=x,t_{n+2}(x,y)=t_{n+1}(x,y)*t_{n}(x,y)$$
for $n\geq 1$. We say that $(X,*,1)$ is permutative if for each $x,y\in X$, there is some $n$ where $t_{n}(x,y)=1$. If $(X,*,1)$ is permutative, then we say that $\mathrm{crit}(x)\leq\mathrm{crit}(y)$ if there is some $n\geq 0$ where $x^{n}*y=1$ where we define $x^{0}*y=y$ and $x^{n+1}*y=x*(x^{n}*y)$.
We say $\mathrm{crit}(x)=\mathrm{crit}(y)$ if $\mathrm{crit}(x)\leq\mathrm{crit}(y)$ and $\mathrm{crit}(y)\leq\mathrm{crit}(x)$ and
$\mathrm{crit}(x)<\mathrm{crit}(y)$ if $\mathrm{crit}(x)\leq\mathrm{crit}(y)$ and $\mathrm{crit}(x)\neq\mathrm{crit}(y)$. The ordering $\{\mathrm{crit}(x)\mid x\in X\}$ is always a linear ordering.

Define $x^{[1]}=x$ and $x^{[n+1]}=x*x^{[n]}$ for $n\geq 1$. Then it is easy to show that $x^{[n+1]}=x^{[n]}*x^{[n]}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Suppose that $n$ is a natural number. Then does there exist a permutative algebra $(X,*,1)$ along with some $x,y\in X$ where
$$\mathrm{crit}(x*y)<\mathrm{crit}(x^{[2]}*y)<\dots<\mathrm{crit}(x^{[n]}*y)?$$ What if we also require $(X,*,1)$ to be finite?

$\textbf{Remark:}$ From an affirmative answer, we can easily conclude that the free self-distributive algebra on arbitrary number of generators embeds into an inverse limit of finite self-distributive algebras, a fact whose only known proof requires very large cardinals. However, permutative algebras $(X,*,1)$ where $\mathrm{crit}(x*y)<\mathrm{crit}((x*x)*y)$ cannot arise from large cardinals.

Comment: is the inequality strict in your question? If so, how do you define strict inequality as opposed to non strict one, i.e., what is the fundamental difference between $crit(x)<crit(y)$ and $crit(x)\le crit(y)$?

Comment: In addition, I think your algebra is associative

Comment: The algebra $(X,*,1)$ is **not** associative whenever $|X|>1$. If $x\neq 1$, then $(x*x)*x\neq x*(x*x)$, and $\mathrm{crit}((x*x)*x)=\mathrm{crit}(x)$ while $\mathrm{crit}(x*(x*x))>\mathrm{crit}(x)$. Mathematicians need to see more examples of non-associative algebraic structures.

Comment: so, I think this is somewhat related to self distributive cryptosystems

Comment: If $n>5$ and $\mathrm{crit}(x^{[n]}*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x*y)$, then $x^{[n]}\neq 1$. The problem is that if $x^{[n]}\neq 1$, then $(X,*)$ must be exceedingly large. Therefore, these large algebras where $\mathrm{crit}(x^{[n]}*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x*y)$ do not serve a cryptographic purpose. The only way that I see one using permutative algebras for cryptographic purposes is to start with a finite permutative algebra $(X,*,1)$ (one could even have $|X|<100$) and an operation $t:X^{2}\rightarrow X$ where $x*t(y,z)=t(x*y,x*z)$ and produce an endomorphic Laver table out of $(X,*,1,t)$.

Comment: And I see a long road ahead for endomorphic Laver table based cryptography since there are zero people in the universe who know much of anything about endomorphic Laver tables and because endomorphic Laver tables have pretty much nothing to do with any well-studied mathematical structure except for very large cardinal embeddings.

Comment: So I was doing some computer calculations, and I have not been able to compute any finite Laver-like algebras $X$ with $\mathrm{crit}(x^{[3]}*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x*y).$ An example of such an algebra would be a good partial answer to this question. Another good partial algebra would be a large lower bound to the cardinality of the smallest Laver-like algebra with $\mathrm{crit}(x^{[3]}*y)>\mathrm{crit}(x*y).$ Maybe that would be a good next question to ask.